# Unable to provision an AWS SQL Server RDS instance in Multi AZ using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm trying to provision an SQL Server Standard Edition AWS RDS instance which is mirrored across two AZs using boto's rds2.

Whenever I call the create_db_instance method in boto.rds2.layer1.RDSConnection with the appropriate arguments, I keep getting the following error:

```
boto.exception.JSONResponseError: JSONResponseError: 400 Bad Request
{'RequestId': 'fdc54b48-0586-11e5-951d-c3153310155b', 'Error': {'Message': 'To configure Multi-AZ for SQL Server DB Instances please apply or remove the "Mirroring" option using Option Groups.', 'Code': 'InvalidParameterCombination', 'Type': 'Sender'}}
```

I've verified that I'm setting the option multi_az = True and the option_group_name is set to an option group which has mirroring enabled. Here's my call to create_db_instance. Are there any other settings which need to be set before I can provision this RDS instance which is mirrored?

```
conn.create_db_instance(db_instance_identifier=new_db_name,
                                    allocated_storage=allocated_storage,
                                    db_instance_class=rds_instance_class,
                                    master_username=master_username,
                                    master_user_password=master_password,
                                    port=port,
                                    engine=rds_engine,
                                    multi_az=rds_multi_az,
                                    auto_minor_version_upgrade=auto_minor_version_upgrade,
                                    db_subnet_group_name=rds_subnet_group,
                                    license_model=license_model,
                                    iops=iops,
                                    vpc_security_group_ids=rds_vpc_security_group,
                                    option_group_name=option_group_name
                                )
```

I'm also seeing another issue where I can either provision with IOPS or provision with Magnetic disks when I remove the iops option. But, I haven't figured out a way to provision with just General Purpose SSDs.

Comment: Which AWS region are you trying ?

Comment: I am trying to provision in Virginia. Btw, I've realized what was wrong. Let me update with an answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue by removing the multi_az option but using an option group which has mirroring set. This way, the RDS server is provisioned across multiple AZs without me specifying the multi_az option. My new call looks like this:

```
conn.create_db_instance(db_instance_identifier=new_db_name,
                                    allocated_storage=allocated_storage,
                                    db_instance_class=rds_instance_class,
                                    master_username=master_username,
                                    master_user_password=master_password,
                                    port=port,
                                    engine=rds_engine,
                                    auto_minor_version_upgrade=auto_minor_version_upgrade,
                                    db_subnet_group_name=rds_subnet_group,
                                    license_model=license_model,
                                    iops=iops,
                                    vpc_security_group_ids=domain_controller_sg,
                                    option_group_name=option_group_name
                                )
```